# Should tenants pay for repairs if it's their fault?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, landlord

Say a tenant accidentally flushed a hard object down the toilet, is it better for the tenant to take care of the plumber bill or call the landlord?  Would this be good grounds for a rental raise in the future if calling the landlord?

Comment: What is your location? In some places there are laws that dictate what tenants are responsible for and for what they need to pay.

Comment: Your question is about paying for repairs, but the body of the question is about who should call a professional. Those can be two very different things.

Comment: You didn't specify what this hard object did to the system? Did it just clog the toilet or does it have downstream effects such as flooding your neighbor's apartment below?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I think it's pretty clear that OP is asking "should tenant pay a plumber out of pocket (for a plumbing repair that is needed because of tenants negligence) or let the landlord deal with it (and accept whatever consequences that may bring)?"

Comment: Likely, the landlord can get a better deal than you can. So even if you were charged 100%, you might end up spending less money than if you did it. And hiring someone yourself may end up with you getting billed a second time to actually fix it.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I am assuming whoever calls is paying the bill.

Comment: If the landlord has to fix a problem directly caused by you (regardless whether it's an accident or malice) then odds are you will pay the bill even if they call the plumber. You might not pay the bill today but you can bet you will not receive 100% of your deposit when you move out. If the landlord thinks this will be a recurring issue then they can choose to not renew your lease. It's best to be honest and not shady unless your landlord treats you poorly.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, That's been my experience.  An apartment building will generally have either a handyman on staff (hourly or salary), or will have one contracted at a good rate.   I lived in a Condo, and the condo had a couple on staff, and would allow owners to pay for minor services, and they were way cheaper than 3rd party.  They also knew the paint, wire, HVAC, plumbing and all of the standards in use.

Comment: @MikeP Even if you're in a small unit, your landlord has hired far more contractors that a typical renter has. While I was renting, I'd have had no idea how to pick a good contractor or what a good rate is.

Answer (score 63):

As a landlord, I would always prefer for you to call me whenever there is an issue. It is possible they might tell you to handle yourself, but they need to be in on the decision. Botched repairs can cause more headache than the original problem.

As to the specifics of who pays for repairs. It is usually spelled out in the lease.

Comment: In other words: tenants won't call if they think you'll raise the rent if they call.

Comment: We can't raise the rent just for the heck of it. You have to do it at the end of a lease period. I'm not going to raise it very often on current tenants, maintenance issues or not. I can't speak for every landlord though. I WANT tenants to call me on maintenance issues. I'd be more likely to raise the rent on tenants that let problems fester from not reporting them.

Comment: In some places, "handle it yourself" isn't an option.

Comment: @user253751 They can't raise the rent. They *can* require you to pay back the cost of repairs though, or subtract it from the deposit you put down at the start of your rental if you leave without paying.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yup. Pretty sure that doing plumbing work isn't legal in Australia unless you're a certified, licensed plumber, for instance.

Comment: "Handle it yourself" doesn't mean to get your own hands dirty. It means you are the one to call the handyman.

Comment: @inf I don't remember where, but I'm fairly certain at least one place I rented you could only call a contractor for emergencies or after some period of time without hearing from your LL. After all, actually calling the contractor is like the bare minimum of being a LL, so it's not that absurd to put that on them.

Answer (score 34):

This is typically spelled out in the lease. Our leases say that

- tenant must call us (the landlords) if something needs to be repaired.
- tenants are responsible for the costs associated with damage above and beyond normal wear-and-tear that is not covered by our insurance.
- repairs must be done by people we choose rather than people the tenant chooses, otherwise the tenant will not be reimbursed.

So far, every incident of plumbing damage that was caused by a tenant's accidental negligence has been fixable by us and hasn't resulted in any extra charges to the tenant. Fire damage has been covered by insurance. Our time is valued at US$50/hr, and if repairs for an incident ever get above $200, we might consider a one-time charge to the tenant.

The third point attempts to preclude claims for non-existent repairs and repairs by acquaintances of the tenants that might be overpriced.

Comment: I thought the third point would be about low-quality repairs, but apparently the world is worse than I thought.

Comment: @Mark It is. Better, too.

Comment: @Mark That may certainly depend on jurisdiction (and what it allows to be written in contracts). E.g., in Germany I would expect a clause about "sach- und fachgerecht" (essentially, done as by a certified specialist craftsperson), but in countries where everybody with a hammer (and without insurance) can call themselves plumber, landlords certainly have a justified desire to be involved in the choice

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm afraid that no amount of paperwork will stop a certified plumber who happens to be a friend of the tenant from charging you more than some other certified plumber would.

Comment: @TooTea maybe in Germany there are government-regulated wage rates?

Comment: @RonJohn Replacing that tap handle was a difficult job. Twenty-three hours labor at [government-mandated rate].

Comment: @fectin you joke, but seemingly simple jobs can turn into legitimately long and complex jobs.

Comment: Either the landlord or the tenant can get their incompetent mate come round to do the job incompetently. I'm not sure why the lanlord should get the gig beyond them being the more powerful party in the contract negotiations. As a tenant, I was always happy to offer to foot the bill if I could choose a craftsperson after the landlords repairs repeatedly left gas and electrical fittings in an objectively dangerous state (as confirmed by the supply companies).

Comment: @DanSheppard both you and the landlord want to do it as cheap as possible, and both have an incentive to bill the other at a high rate.

Comment: @DanSheppard besides, it's the lardlord's property.  He gets to decide who repairs it.  You get to sue him if he doesn't, or does a crappy job.

Comment: @RonJohn And it's only the tenants life?

Comment: @DanSheppard please be more specific in your question.

Comment: @TooTea and what about certified plumbers who are friends of the landlord?

Comment: @DanSheppard Because maintaining the property is practically the only obligation a landlord has to their tenant. You definitely should *not* have been happy to put money into your landlord's property for them.

Answer (score 10):

I have been a landlord.

There are two questions in this question:

- Who initiates the repair process?
- Who pays for the repair?

You as the tenant have to return the rental property back to the owner at the end of the lease in working condition, or you may be responsible for the repair cost. There are of course allowances for normal wear and tear.

So, if you caused the damage, you may be responsible for the cost.

The question remains: who initiates the repair? If the full cost of the repair isn't easily determined, or if the repair/replacement will change the structure or a fixture, then it is best to call the landlord or their representative first.

First, some examples:

- Break a light fixture that is hanging in the kitchen.
- Break the door to the bathroom
- Punch a hole in the wall
- The heat pump dies.

If you buy a replacement light fixture and it doesn't match what was there, it will be noticed during the inspection, and the tenant will pay for the one the landlord has installed, but the tenant does get to keep the one he originally paid for. This also applies to a toilet, sink, or refrigerator.

If you don't know how to hang a door, or you have no idea what color/type of paint is in the rest of the unit, you may have to pay for a second door, or for it to get repainted.

Wall repair can be tricky; doing it yourself or having a friend do it can make the situation worse. Plus there is still a paint problem.

The heat pump can be a big cost, and the repair can range from an amount covered by the annual maintenance contract to a total replacement.

If you have any doubts, please consult the rental contract and contact the landlord. Calling them doesn't change who pays what, but it may avoid the situation where the tenant pays unnecessary costs or makes the situation worse.

Answer (score 9):

> is it better for the tenant to take care of the plumber bill or call the landlord?

Depends. Tell me how you take care of the damage that you may have caused that are not part of your rented property (i.e. damage to the fall drain when you rent an appartment in the 6th floor). Also the landlord has a right for a professional repair - so "taking care yourself" may end up with an invoice from the landlord if you do it yourself and it is not done to professional standards.

> Would this be good grounds for a rental raise in the future if calling the landlord?

No. Because the renter has to pay damage caused by abuse/gross neglect. To 100% on top of the rent. There is no damage left to justify a raise in rent. That said, not every country has sane laws, and if you are totally free to renegotiate rent, i.e. after a year, the landlord can do what he wants.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't share your location, but I've had a similar experience in the US.  I was renting a house and was in the process of having cable TV service connected.  The house only had a single cable TV jack, so I asked the installer to wire a second jack on the other end of the house.  The installer said that since I was merely a renter and not the property owner, they could not do any sort of work on the house.  They could connect service since that was done outside the house, but any repairs or modifications to the house require explicit permission from the property owner.  Doing that sort of work without owner permission opens them up to a bunch of legal problems (the owner could consider their unauthorized work "property damage" and sue, the cable company's insurance that covers injury and property damage doesn't cover unauthorized work, etc).

Long story short, you may not be able to get a plumber to agree to do the work if you try to call them yourself.  Even if you impersonate the homeowner and sign off on the work, there could be ugly legal issues if something goes wrong.  Your best bet is just to call the landlord.  If you're worried about the landlord being upset about the expense, you can always offer to reimburse them for the cost of the plumber visit (if they can't fix the problem themselves).

I wouldn't imagine a reasonable landlord would hold it against you if you report an fairly routine plumbing problem like that (especially if you offer to cover the cost) unless it becomes frequent or exorbitantly expensive. On the other hand, a reasonable landlord would be *very* upset if you have to call and say "we have a plumbing problem, I tried to have it fixed without telling you, and now we have *two* plumbing problems".  The latter shows a disrespect for the property, would make me wonder what else you've hidden, and would make me think twice about renewing your lease at all.

Comment: Many people (perhaps most?) don't expect landlords to be reasonable. We've all heard the horror stories.

Comment: @user253751 I'd bet money an average landlord is more reasonable than an average tenant.